# Firefox add-on background script stopped in new Firefox version

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-developer-tools

My Firefox add-on background script stopped working in the latest version of Firefox.  I've been using this add-on without changes for over a year now and it has been working perfectly so something in the recent Firefox updates broke the add-on. I'm on version 106.0.1 now. When I go to debug add-ons I can see the background script is stopped.

In the manifest.json (version 2)

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
},
```

In the background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    console.log('Installed');
    setUpdateAlarm();
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
    console.log('Startup');
    setUpdateAlarm();
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((alarm) => {
    console.log('Alarm: ' + alarm.name);
    switch (alarm.name) {
        case 'Refresh':
            updateCache();
            break;
    }
});

function setUpdateAlarm() {
    updateCache();
    chrome.alarms.create('Refresh', { periodInMinutes: 3 });
}
```

Keep in mind that neither of these files have changed but Firefox has been updated.

Comment: New Firefox added support for persistent:false but it's probably still bugged, so you can report it on bugzilla.

Comment: Why does this question have the `google-chrome-extension` tag, when it's specifically about Firefox?